# How to use parse server and express with NextJS?

Tags: express, next.js, parse-platform

I'm currently trying to use parse server and express with my express app, however it's my first time working with servers and I'm not able to understand how exactly the rendering and routing work. Here is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
const path = require('path');


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1338;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const hostname = 'localhost'
const app = next({ dev, hostname, PORT });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

const databaseUri = 'mongodb+srv://';

if (!databaseUri) {
    console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
  }


const config = {
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb+srv://',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || '',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1338/parse', // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ['Posts', 'Comments'], // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  },
};


app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    const showRoutes = require("./routes/index.js");

    server.use("/api", showRoutes(server));
    server.use('/pages', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/pages')));

    const mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';

    const api = new ParseServer(config);
    server.use(mountPath, api);
    

    // server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    //   return handle(req, res);
    // });

    // server.get('/', function (req, res) {
    //     res.status(200).send('I dream of being a website.  Please star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
    //   });

    server.get('/',function(req,res){
        return app.render(req, res, '/pages/index', req.query)
      });

    server.get('/test', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
      });

    const httpServer = require('http').createServer(server);
    httpServer.listen(PORT, function () {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + PORT + '.');
    });

    ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);

    module.exports = {
        app,
        config,
      }
    }
  )
```

When I run this code, the homepage loads blank, however the terminal does not show any errors. I have also added the render() function in my index page, however that does not seem to be working.

If someone can point out any setup mistakes I've made and explain how I can configure nextjs with parse and express to correctly route/render, I'd be extremely grateful.

It's extremely difficult to find help with the following setup online, so if someone could point to any example github repos or learning material that would be extremely helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add something like:

```
server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
})
```

Honestly, I'd recommend you to run two web servers: one for the next.js app (maybe using `create-next-app` script), and another for the the Parse Server app. Anyways, if you decide to put the two things together in the same server, I'd try first to setup next.js. Once it is working, I'd add Parse Server code.